# Hiding a particular error message from query results in google cloud logging

Tags: google-cloud-logging

How to hide the repetitive log message ("Got more than one input Future failure. Logging failures after the first) as in below image. Because i want to see the other error messages.
[image]

Comment: You may able to set up a filter such that these messages are filtered _out_ when viewing.  This would hide all of them, not just the first one.

Comment: Could you provide me any sample query to filter out a particular error msg from query result.

Comment: I don't have similar log data to you immediately to hand ... however, if you expand a log record and then pick a field (eg. logName) then when you click on it, you will see a context menu with the option ... "Hide matching entries".

Answer (score 4):

At GCP Console, in “Logs Explorer” at “Query preview” you can set a filter condition.
You can define a restrictive filter for some messages and, as Kolban commented, It would hide all of them, not only the first one.
For example if you do not want to show all the log entries from a particular resource like “gce_instance”, this would be the advanced filter to use:

```
NOT resource.type="gce_instance"
```

In your situation, you can use this filter:

```
NOT "Got more than one input Future failure. Logging failures after the first”
```

This is explained in  the  [advanced log queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries)

Comment: severity=ERROR
logName="projects/logs/onprem-sync-production" AND 
NOT "Got more than one input Future failure. Logging failures after the first”

When i use NOT as above in the query i am getting syntax error.